# JavaScript enable button not working in php

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have used Javascript to enable or disable a button, depending on the input value. I'm  new to PHP, so I don't know why this isn't working. Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once('header.php');
include_once('functions.php');

$_SESSION['userid'] = 1;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Microblogging Application</title>
</head>
vbody>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['message'])){
    echo "<b>". $_SESSION['message']."</b>";
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
?>
<form method='post' action='add.php'>
<p>Your status:</p>
<textarea name='body' rows='5' cols='40' wrap=VIRTUAL></textarea>

<input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="text" name="poscode" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" disabled="disabled"/>




</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[name="age"], input[name="poscode"]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val())
  {
    $("input[name='submit']").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});

</script>
<?php
$posts = show_posts($_SESSION['userid']);

if (count($posts)){
?>
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' width='500'>
<?php
foreach ($posts as $key => $list){
    echo "<tr valign='top'>\n";

    echo "<td>".$list['body'] ."<br/>\n";
    echo "<small>".$list['stamp'] ."</small></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}else{
?>
<p><b>You haven't posted anything yet!</b></p>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I change it so when the value of the input = "foo", the button is now clickable. 

Thanks in advance


-Ben

Comment: here: `<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[name="age"], input[name="poscode"]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val())
  {
    $("input[name='submit']").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});

</script>`

Comment: To let you know, PHP has not a slightest relation to JavaScript. So, JS cannot be "working" or "not working" in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't make sense of your question, but if you're asking what I think you're asking (which is "how do I enable the button if the form is populated on page load?"), change your script to the following:

```
$.ready(function(){
    $('input[name="age"], input[name="poscode"]').change(function(){
      if ($(this).val())
      {
        $("input[name='submit']").removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    }).change();
});
```

I added the change call to trigger the change event handler, and wrapped it in jQuery's ready handler.

Comment: Please define "not working", and define what it is you really want to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, I just want so when someone enters age in the input, the button is not disabled. I don't know if its in my php right or what...

Comment: Do you want to do that server-side or client side?

Comment: Then it probably has to do with the fact that jQuery may not be initialized by the time you define your event handler. Answer updated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6495/discussion-between-kenaniah-and-ben-thomson)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the attr function like below

```
$('#element').attr('disabled', true);
```

Or

```
$('#element').attr('disabled', false);
```

Because different browsers treat the disbaled attribute differently, using `true` and `false` lets jquery handle the cross browser issues